# Export entries and multiple custom field meta to .csv?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, sql, export, csv

First time poster. I'm trying to export a bunch of custom posts out to a csv file so I can easily import them into a new database. I've ran the native export to xml, but it's not the correct format I need. I need a column based format (ie. name, height, weight, etc.).

I have a custom post that has several custom fields. I'm having issues combining them all down to one single row, rather than a new row for each meta type. Is there a way to write a sql query that has numerous selects for each meta type and combines them into one row with multiple columns?

Here is what I have so far, which gives me one column and a new row for each meta type for the same Name

```
SELECT p.post_title AS Name
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm 
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'prospects'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Now how would I start adding columns (selects) for each meta type and combine them on one row:

```
AND (
  SELECT m1.meta_value AS Height
  WHERE m1.meta_key = '_height'
)
AND (
  SELECT m2.meta_value AS Weight
  WHERE m2.meta_key = '_weight'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @toscho pointing out `get_post();`, I was able to spit out a .csv with a blank template. At first, I had memory limit issues b/c of the amount of data, so I moved the site locally and was able to get everything I need with the `get_post();`

This is the gist of it:

```
<ol>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'prospects',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><?php echo $post->ID ?>, <?php the_title(); ?>, <?php echo get_field('prospect_profile_image'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('height'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('weight'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('born'); ?>, , <?php echo get_field('email'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('phone'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('street_address'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('city'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('state'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('zip_code'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('position_1'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('position_2'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('bats'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('throws'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('fathers_name'); ?>, <?php echo get_field('mothers_name'); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

I used an orderlist at first to make sure I was getting all the records.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and iterate over the result array. The argument `'numberposts' => -1` will produce a complete list of the posts.

If you look at `WP_Query::get_posts()` in `wp-includes/query.php` you may get an idea how terrible complex such a query is (which is no excuse for the code style in this function …).

And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, wasn't sure on how to subscribe to this thread. 

Thanks for some insight. I'll give this a try and let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: I'm starting off simple and then I will start to expand the export template to get the data I need. This is what I have so far and it returns the start of the template: <ul> that's it. 

`<?php /* Template Name: Player Export */ ?> <ul> <?php global $post; $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'prospects', 'post_status' => 'publish' ); $myposts = get_posts( $args ); foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?> <li><?php the_title(); ?></li> <?php endforeach; ?> </ul>`